# How do I add Minecraft to Steam?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, steam

I want to add Minecraft to Steam, but am not sure which files to add. How do I add Minecraft to Steam?

Comment: <strike>I don't get it.</strike> nevermind.

Comment: You could use the minecraft.jar file as of now too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only file you'll need to add to Steam to be able to play Minecraft is the Minecraft.exe.

Comment: I don't think that really answers the question...

Comment: "but am not sure which files to add" - I think it does. I just assumed (possibly incorrectly) that he already knew how to add a non-Steam game since the question was asking for the specific file.

Comment: Fair enough, but you don't answer "How do I add Minecraft to Steam?" which is also the title answer.

Comment: @Pureferret I disagree. I think this answers the question perfectly. Could you expand more on how this doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @Wipqozn If I was the OP I'd be wondering what to do with the .exe file. Murgatroid answers this perfectly.

Comment: @Pureferret The OP specifically asked for what file to add. Tristan told him what file to add. The fact that I answered a broader question does not make this answer wrong.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I didn't say it was wrong. It doesn't *really* answer the question. I guess I should have said it was incomplete, as far as I can tell, because the OP asks for two things. Tristran answers one of those things fine. But as it doesn't address the other part, I wouldn't say it 'really' answers it. I was a bit heavy handed with my downvote, but I cant take it back. :(

Comment: @Pureferret I see what you're saying now, and that makes perfect sense. I got the same impression that tristan did, that the OP already knew how to add non-steam games to steam, but just didn't know which files to add for minecraft.

Comment: @Pureferret you can take it back now if you want.

Comment: The question itself implies that the OP knows how to add games to Steam in general, so I think this answer is fine. That being said, @murgatroid99 's answer is better.

Comment: The question does. The question title, not so much. Googlers come here seeing the title. @murgatroid99's answer is better.

Comment: I googled "How do I add minecraft to Steam"  and came to this question, obviously because it matches the title of the post *verbatim*.  This answer DID NOT help me solve my problem.  It does not answer the question "How do I add minecraft to steam" which is in the subject AND the body.  If you guys want to be pedantic, he never specifically asked "Which file do I add?".  He asked 'HOW DO I ADD MINECRAFT TO STEAM?".  The answer "minecraft.exe" DOES NOT answer the question.

Answer (score 32):

You just have to add the `minecraft.exe` file. On my Windows machine it is under `Program Files/Minecraft`, but I am not sure if that is consistent. In any case, you can just search for `minecraft.exe` file and add it wherever you find it.

To actually add it to Steam, you just have to go to the "Games" menu and click on "Add a Non-Steam Game to My Library...". In the window that opens, either choose `minecraft.exe` if it is in the list or browse for it in whatever location you found it in.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the standard method of adding `minecraft.exe` as a non-steam game wasn't helpful as I needed a method that works in Steam Big Picture mode without going back to the desktop view. To do this, you first need to skip the Minecraft launcher as explained in this question: [Can I bypass the new launcher?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122802/can-i-bypass-the-new-launcher)

That method should give you `.bat` file that you can run that will skip the Minecraft launcher. However, since Steam's "*Add a non-Steam game*" feature only allows you to select executables with an `.exe` extension, you will need to do the following to run the newly created batch script from Steam:

- *Add a non-Steam game* and choose any application/game
- Right-click on the newly added application in your Steam game list and select *properties*
- Change the *target* field to point to your new batch script and the *start in* field to point to it's directory, and then also change the name/icon to identify it as Minecraft.