# Is there a way to run Minecraft 1.7.9 from the command line, and connect to a server without seeing the launcher or main menu?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to set up an easy way to get into a server I'm running by just clicking on a .bat file or .command file, on PC and Mac, and I've found guides for getting it to work for 1.6 or 1.7.4, but none of them work any more for 1.7.9. Does anyone here know if there is a way currently?

Comment: Anything that works for 1.7.4 should work for 1.7.9.  However, I don't believe this is possible in any version of Minecraft.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I bypass the new launcher?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122802/can-i-bypass-the-new-launcher)

Answer (score -3):

If you are trying to set up a craftbukkit server, you should use this:

```
java -Xmx2000M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true
PAUSE
```

But for this to work you need to download a craftbukkit server here:

https://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/craftbukkit/

Since Minecraft 1.7.5 and 1.7.9 are very similar, meaning that you can connect to a 1.7.5 server while using version 1.7.9, this should work. there are also lots of tutorials on youtube as well.

As of to my knowledge and research, there isn't any way to do this with a vanilla server however.

I hope this helped in any way.

Comment: Doesn't that start the server itself? I think the OP is looking into starting the client and connecting to an already-running server.

Comment: Yes that is what it does, I thought he was asking how to create a server and not connect to an already running server...he needs to specify that :/