# How do automatically launch Minecraft, skip pressing the play button, and just have it go straight to the menu?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows

I want to just click the shortcut and have it automatically launch, going straight to the game menu instead of having to click the play button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I bypass the new launcher?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122802/can-i-bypass-the-new-launcher)