# Is it posible to run Minecraft 1.10 without the launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, steam

I've got an HTC Vive, and so going through the normal Minecraft launcher to play in VR is a pain, since I have to start the game and then switch to desktop mode to actually click launch.

What I want to do is create a .BAT file and link that into Steam, so I can kick the game off in one shot.

How could this be done?

Comment: The launcher sets your session ID, verifies credentials, etc. You'd have to rewrite all that in order to do this.

Comment: You can try this solution which worked for 1.11: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122802/can-i-bypass-the-new-launcher/306709#306709

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Silveri's comment.

Answer (score -2):

Quote of Jonno in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531917/launch-minecraft-from-command-line-usename-and-password-as-prefix
**I don't know how to get this to work, assuming it can still work...**
(I think you have to drop the batch file into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft") PS: Sorry for formatting failure, this is my first post

> Just create this batch command file in your game directory. Bat file takes one argument %1 as the username.
>
> Also, I use a splash screen to make pretty. You will NOT be able to play online, but who cares.
>
> Adjust your memory usage to fit your machine (-Xmx & -Xmns).
>
> NOTE: this is for version of minecraft as of 2016-06-27
>
> ! @ECHO OFF
>
> SET DIR=%cd%
>
> SET JAVA_HOME=%DIR%\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25
>
> SET JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe
>
> SET LOW_MEM=768M
>
> SET MAX_MEM=2G
>
> SET LIBRARIES=versions\1.10.2\1.10.2-natives-59894925878961
>
> SET CLASSPATH=libraries\com\mojang\netty\1.6\netty-1.6.jar;libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar;libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\3.4.0\jna-3.4.0.jar;libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.6\jopt-simple-4.6.jar;libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.23.Final\netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar;libraries\com\google\guava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar;libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.22\authlib-1.5.22.jar;libraries\com\mojang\realms\1.9.3\realms-1.9.3.jar;libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\7.0.12_mojang\fastutil-7.0.12_mojang.jar;libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;versions\1.10.2\1.10.2.jar
>
> SET JAVA_OPTIONS=-server -splash:splash.png -d64 -da -dsa -Xrs -Xms%LOW_MEM% -Xmx%MAX_MEM% -XX:NewSize=%LOW_MEM% -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.library.path=%LIBRARIES% -cp %CLASSPATH%  %MAIN_CLASS%
>
> start /D %DIR% /I /HIGH %JAVA% %JAVA_OPTIONS% --username %1 --version 1.10.2 --gameDir %DIR% --assetsDir assets --assetIndex 1.10 --uuid 2536abce90e8476a871679918164abc5 --accessToken 99abe417230342cb8e9e2168ab46297a --userType legacy --versionType release --nativeLauncherVersion 307

Comment: It's ugly. It will only work for one specific version, with no hope of manually updating it due to scope. It will not allow mods. Attitude of `I don't know how to get this to work, assuming it can still work` doesn't suit this site very well. And yet it might actually work

Comment: This won't work for 1.10.

Comment: I am sorry for not being able to format it properly, but I did link to a page with the proper formatting, I merely copied the post in case the other comment gets removed and or the thread gets taken down. _Does everyone down vote every post they see?_

Comment: If what SevenSidedDie says is true - there is nothing wrong here, answers that don't work SHOULD get downvotes. I know you don't have the ability to comment yet, but a link with information that could be helpfull that you didn't check yourself is comment material.

Answer (score -3):

You can download Minecraft without a launcher [here](https://minecraft.net/en/download/alternative)

Use the first one

(Just in case "here" doesn't work: https://minecraft.net/en/download/alternative)

Comment: All of those include launchers, and the one that doesn't is the server version, which is no use here.