# Minecraft launcher is unresponsive

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I enter minecraft it is unresponsive to any clicking. For login I can simply do - tab - enter username - tab - enter password - press enter, but then when I reach launcher screen I can't get further. Buttons high light blue when I hover over them but they do not respond to clicking. I tried multiple options and long story short even reinstalled windows, but still the same problem. Is there a way to skip launcher? Please help.

Comment: Can you provide us with a screenshot so we know what's going on here?

Comment: Is your question  *Is there a way to skip launcher?*

Comment: Try uninstalling it and installing it back.

Comment: I have had the same issue once before and it fixed itself with a reinstall.  But i can't give you a better awnser if you've tried that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I bypass the new launcher?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122802/can-i-bypass-the-new-launcher)

Answer (score -1):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to cycle through the buttons.

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot even get onto the game, your device may not have sufficient RAM or doesn't have a good graphics card/driver. I would recommend a 3GB RAM and an Intel Graphics card.