# How to run Minecraft Java without the launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I am creating my own Minecraft launcher and I want to know the terminal command for opening Minecraft Java. I've tried many solutions online but most of them are outdated or only for Windows.

I already authenticated with https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate, and now I want to run a terminal command which opens Minecraft given the username/password or access token.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I bypass the new launcher?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122802/can-i-bypass-the-new-launcher)