# How to start Minecraft from the command line?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I start modern Minecraft versions, 1.19+, from the command line?

I guess that there exists a tool which can read the version's JSON and generate the startup command, but I've not been able to find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Can I bypass the new launcher?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122802/can-i-bypass-the-new-launcher) (and yes, the answer should be merged by a moderator)